# group by and having clause issue

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table obl_books, obl_authors and the link table books_authors.
The question is:
Write a query to select only those books whose all authors belong to Indian Nationality.

And the query I wrote for this is

```
SELECT obl_books.*, books_authors.author_id
   FROM books_authors,obl_authors,obl_books
   WHERE   books_authors.author_id = obl_authors.author_id
   AND books_authors.book_id=obl_books.book_id
    GROUP BY books_authors.book_id
    HAVING  books_authors.author_id IN (SELECT obl_authors.author_id FROM obl_authors WHERE nationality='Indian')
```

Nationality is the column of obl_authors table and a book can have many authors.

So if book_id (2) has author_id (1), author_id (2) where author_id (1) and (2) are Indians then it should return that and if even one of the author is not Indian it should not.

But my query is returning even that book_id.

I even changed my having clause using ALL keyword in place of IN but it does not return any row.

Comment: why group by clause ?

Comment: Post the table structure with sample data

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SELECT obl_books.*, GROUP_CONCAT(books_authors.author_id)
FROM books_authors
JOIN obl_authors ON books_authors.author_id = obl_authors.author_id
JOIN obl_books ON books_authors.book_id=obl_books.book_id
GROUP BY books_authors.book_id
HAVING MIN(obl_authors.nationality)='Indian' AND 
       MAX(obl_authors.nationality)='Indian'
```

Comment: ohh wow..it worked ..but can you please explain... iam new to sql :(

Comment: The GROUP BY summarises the tables by book_id, then the MIN and MAX check to see whether the (alphabetically) first and last nationalities for each book are 'Indian' - where both conditions are true, that means that there can only be Indian writers for that particular book.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your problem, this is what you want; it just counts whether the number of indian authors is the same as the number of total authors per book, and show the ones where they're equal.

```sql
SELECT b.*, GROUP_CONCAT(a.author_id) authors
FROM obl_books b 
JOIN books_authors ba ON b.book_id=ba.book_id
LEFT JOIN obl_authors a ON ba.author_id=a.author_id AND a.nationality = 'Indian'
GROUP BY b.book_id
HAVING COUNT(a.author_id)=COUNT(ba.author_id)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94f74/2).

Note that the `GROUP BY` on book_id only is a MySQL'ism, you'd normally need to group by all selected fields in `obl_books`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one query:

```
SELECT obl_books.*, books_authors.author_id
   FROM books_authors,obl_authors,obl_books
   WHERE   books_authors.author_id = obl_authors.author_id
   AND books_authors.book_id=obl_books.book_id and obl_authors.nationality='Indian'
   GROUP BY books_authors.book_id
   HAVING count(books_authors.book_id) = (SELECT count(*) FROM books_authors group by books_authors.author_id)
```

Comment: It does not work..it gives all those book ids even if there is one author who is an indian.. but I want only those book_id wherein all its authors are indian

Comment: I see, I have changed the query. Try another one.

Answer (score 0):

I think, we can do this.. in reverse way also.. First get all the author id,who is not Indian and then except those author select all the remaining author's book (Indian Author's book).

```
 SELECT obl_books.*, books_authors.author_id
   FROM books_authors,obl_authors,obl_books
   WHERE   books_authors.author_id = obl_authors.author_id
   AND books_authors.book_id=obl_books.book_id AND  books_authors.author_id NOT IN (SELECT obl_authors.author_id FROM obl_authors WHERE nationality<>'Indian')
```

Comment: It does not work..it gives all those book ids even if there is one author who is an indian.. but I want only those book_id wherein all its authors are indian

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from obl_books where id in (select book_id from books_authors where author_id in (select id from obl_authors where nationality='Indian'))
```